# How to better balance state taxes when working in another state

Tags: united-states, state-income-tax, new-york, withholding, new-jersey

I/we live in New York and my wife works in New Jersey. Whenever I file our taxes, the New Jersey non-resident return is pretty balanced. However, my New York return always has NY state owing us a considerable amount.

What do I need to tweak in my wife's (or my own) withholdings to fix this? Note, I work in NY state.

Answer (score 2):

To increase or decrease the amount being withheld for state taxes because every year you are out of balance, then always go to the state version of the w-4.

There are generally worksheets that help the situation when married or if you have multiple jobs or both.

For New York state the [IT-2104 Instructions] are quite complex and there have been changes:

> Changes effective beginning 2022
>
> Form IT-2104 has been revised for tax year 2022. The worksheet and the
> charts below, used to compute withholding allowances or to enter an
> additional dollar amount on line 3, 4, or 5, have been revised. If you
> previously filed a Form IT-2104 and used the worksheet or charts, you
> should complete a new 2023 Form IT-2104 and give it to your employer.

The section " Who should file this form" has a long list that includes:

> you owed tax or received a large refund when you filed your personal
> income tax return for the past year

Make a change to the form, send it to your employer, and then see if the changes do what you expect. Then either keep the changes or make more changes.